# csv Pandas datetime convert time to seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, datetime

I work with data from Datalogger and the timestap is not supported by datetime in the Pandas Dataframe.

I would like to convert this timestamp into a format pandas knows and the then convert the datetime into seconds, starting with 0.

```
>>>df.time
0    05/20/2019 19:20:27:374
1    05/20/2019 19:20:28:674
2    05/20/2019 19:20:29:874
3    05/20/2019 19:20:30:274
Name: time, dtype: object
```

I tried to convert it from the object into datetime64[ns]. with %m or %b for month.

```
df_time = pd.to_datetime(df["time"], format = '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S:%MS')
df_time = pd.to_datetime(df["time"], format = '%b/%d/%y %H:%M:%S:%MS')
```

with error: redefinition of group name 'M' as group 7; was group 5 at position 155

I tried to reduce the data set and remove the milliseconds without success.

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],).str[:-3]
```

ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '05/20/2019 19:20:26:383')

or is it possible to just subtract the first time line from all the other values in the column time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S:%f'` as format instead of `'%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S:%MS'`

Here is the format [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for future reference

Comment: make sure you use capital Y instead of y

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are looking for but you can use the above example to format your output and then you can remove items from your results like the microseconds this way:

```
date = str(datetime.now())
print(date)
2019-07-28 14:04:28.986601
print(date[11:-7])
14:04:28
time = date[11:-7]
print(time)
14:04:28
```